# Is it conventional to call a var "id" in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective-C, we were not able to call a variable `id` because of the type `id`. But in Swift we can. I have a simple question: Is it a good practice?

```
class MyClass {
    var id: Int
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think Swift is more of an ego thing.

Comment: But what do your ego says?

Comment: if the language allows that i think its not bad. Youre not calling it l00kmYaWeSoMeFanCYvAR (HOYGAN style)

Comment: This is primarily an opinion based question (voted to close).

Comment: It's a question of good practice.

Comment: I would avoid it.  What if someome were to use that code and call it from Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, naming a variable/property/field *only* "id" is not good practice (but it's no different from only naming it "identifier".

The problem in both cases is that it's ambiguous what it *is*. An identifier *for what*? You will likely find that it's the identifier *for* something. Then rename it accordingly.

Here are some Cocoa examples:

- `faceID` (identifier for the face in a AVMetaDataFaceObject)
- `recordID` (identifier for a CKRecord)
- `trackID` (identifier for an AVAssetTrack)
- `modelID` (model of device in AVCaptureDevice)
- `matchID`(string that identifies a GKTurnBasedMatch)
- `accessibilityIdentifier` (string that identifies an accessibility element)
- `eventIdentifier` (identifier for an EKEvent)

etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. `id` is not good at all because of the ambiguity and the reason that it is not compatible with Objective-C.

Comment: But if you have a ```struct Foo``` then would you have all members prefixed by ```foo```? I would say to be consistent one would also name the member ```ID``` or a variant thereof.